# Ajax multiple scripts, only one works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a base document in which I am changing the content of  tags with ajax.
I don't know much about javascript. I mainly copied my javascript from w3schools [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first), because it did exactly what I wanted.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title p-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" onclick="loadDoc()"><b>1.1</b> Kräfte und Momente in der Ebene</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                <center>
                <div id="f11">    
                A
                </div>   
                </center> 


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title p-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" onclick="loadDoc()"><b>1.2</b> Irgendwas anderes</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                <center>
                <div id="f12">    
                A
                </div>   
                </center> 


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In ths code I am replacing the content of the div tags id="11" and id="12" with a carusel from an external .php file. With the following script.

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("f11").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "car/c1.1.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

When having only one script, it works, but when adding a second one, in which I **only** change f11 to f12 and car/c1.1.php to car/c1.2.php, only one of them works.
How can I get it to work, so that no matter which part of the accordeon I unfold it loads the .php part into the site?

Followup: On the final page there would be about 23 unfoldable parts, which by the current state would all require an unique script. Is this going to work?

If there is a different solution to load specific markup into the page, when unfolding I would be glad to find out about it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by replacing this 'this.' with this 'xhttp .' in your loadDoc() function.

Comment: Well are the all named loadDoc? Each function would overwrite the last....

Comment: @CharlesEF Why would they do that? `this` is fine.

Comment: @epascarello I tried changing the name, but by doing so, both don't work.

Comment: Well did you than use getElementsByName or querySelectorAll('[name="foo"]')

Comment: @epascarello I just changed the name. I honestly know close to 0 about javascript. changing `getElementById("f00")` to `querySelectorAll('[name="foo"]')` doesn't work. Could you please explain closer what you mean? I am pretty sure the problem lies in the javascript.

Comment: `foo` would need to be changed to the name of the item.... Did you change that?

Comment: @epascarello yes I did that. I will try it again in case I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the function reusable, by passing in arguments:

```js
function loadDoc(target, endpoint) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", endpoint, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title p-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" onclick="loadDoc('f11','https://httpbin.org/get?f11=true')"><b>1.1</b> Kräfte und Momente in der Ebene</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                <center>
                <div id="f11">    
                A
                </div>   
                </center> 


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title p-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" onclick="loadDoc('f12','https://httpbin.org/get?f12=true')"><b>1.2</b> Irgendwas anderes</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                <center>
                <div id="f12">    
                A
                </div>   
                </center> 


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```